# При клике на кнопку, показать модальное окно с информацией о браузере

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Пробовал использовать библиотеки, но не получается. Получилось только вывести в алерте название браузера, без информации о версии и тд. Подскажите пожалуйста хороший способ.

JS

```
function get_name_browser(){

    var ua = navigator.userAgent;    

    if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > 0) return 'Google Chrome';
    if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > 0) return 'Firefox';
    if (ua.search(/Opera/) > 0) return 'Opera';
    if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return 'Safari';
    if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return 'Internet Explorer';

    return 'Не определен';
}

var browser = get_name_browser();
alert(browser);
```

Comment: А у вас уже есть код, который просто выводит информацию о браузере?

Comment: Гляньте пожалуйста выше, я обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего следует отметить, что в userAgent'e Opera нету слова "Opera", вместо него есть "OPR". Слово "Chrome" есть в агенте и Хрома, и Оперы, также слово Safari.

Вот рабочий JavaScript для проверки браузеров Chrome, Opera, Firefox и Internet Explorer, их версий и языка:

```js
document.getElementById('browser_version').addEventListener('click', function(){

    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    var browser, version, language;
    if(~userAgent.indexOf(' Chrome/')) {
     if(~userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/')) {
      browser = 'Opera';
      version = userAgent.split(' OPR/')[1];
     } else {
      browser = 'Google Chrome';
      version = userAgent.split(' Chrome/')[1].split(' ')[0];
     }
    }
    if(~userAgent.indexOf(' Firefox/')) {
     browser = 'Mozilla Firefox';
     version = userAgent.split(' Firefox/')[1];
    }
    if(~userAgent.indexOf(' MSIE ')) {
     browser = 'Internet Explorer';
     version = userAgent.split(' MSIE ')[1].split(';')[0];
    }
 if(~navigator.language.indexOf('en')) {
  language = 'Английский';
 }
 if(~navigator.language.indexOf('ru')) {
  language = 'Русский';
 }
    alert(browser+' '+version+' ' +language);
});
```

```html
<button id="browser_version">Браузер, его версия и язык</button>
```

Comment: Что значит `~` перед переменной?

Comment: @Kosmos то же самое что `str.indexOf() != -1` только more fancy :) [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178020/3208225](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178020/3208225)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня почему-то не запускается функция, нажимаю на кнопку и в консоли вижу Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @Lev в html-коде кнопка должна иметь тот же id что в JavaScript, и html должен быть ПЕРЕД JavaScript. Если ответ подходит, можете плюсануть его и выбрать как принятый

Answer (score 2):

Вся информация о браузере находится в [Window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator). Вывести все его свойства Вы можете с помощью цикла:

```js
for(var key in window.navigator) {
  console.log("%o: %o", key, window.navigator[key]);
}
```

Comment: Как теперь привязать это к кнопке и вывести в модальном окне красиво только нужную информацию, а именно "appVersion" "platform", "language". Чтобы было написано например Хром версия такая-то, язык такой-то

Comment: @Lev язык достаточно например "en" или "Английский"?

Comment: Английский - было бы лучше :)

Comment: @Lev гляньте мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function cBrowser() {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent;
  var bName = function () {
   if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > -1) return "ie";
   if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > -1) return "firefox";
   if (ua.search(/Opera/) > -1) return "opera";
   if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > -1) return "chrome";
   if (ua.search(/Safari/) > -1) return "safari";
   if (ua.search(/Konqueror/) > -1) return "konqueror";
   if (ua.search(/Iceweasel/) > -1) return "iceweasel";
   if (ua.search(/SeaMonkey/) > -1) return "seamonkey";}();
  var version = function (bName) {
   switch (bName) {
    case "ie" : return (ua.split("MSIE ")[1]).split(";")[0];break;
    case "firefox" : return ua.split("Firefox/")[1];break;
    case "opera" : return ua.split("Version/")[1];break;
    case "chrome" : return (ua.split("Chrome/")[1]).split(" ")[0];break;
    case "safari" : return (ua.split("Version/")[1]).split(" ")[0];break;
    case "konqueror" : return (ua.split("KHTML/")[1]).split(" ")[0];break;
    case "iceweasel" : return (ua.split("Iceweasel/")[1]).split(" ")[0];break;
    case "seamonkey" : return ua.split("SeaMonkey/")[1];break;
   }}(bName);
  return bName +' '+ version;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="alert(cBrowser());">123</button>
```